# Coverlet returning 0 % coverage

Tags: c#, teamcity, xunit, reportgenerator, coverlet

I'm trying to use the `coverlet` tool in `dotnet test` to recieve coverage for my `xunit` test. the xunit test executes `UI Automation tests` using a tool called `Rapise`. Since coverlet works only with dotnet sdk style projects, i have converted the xunit test to dotnet sdk style cs project. Also i'm using a tool called `reportgenerator` to get coverage report in `teamcity`. I have modified my `csproj` file and added the necessary package references to `coverlet` and `reportgenerator` packages.

This is what my `csproj file properties` looks like after adding coverlet:

[image]

in `teamcity server` i'm executing the following code:

`"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test D:\BuildAgent\work\workdir\Solution\XUnitTests.UITests1\UITests1.csproj --configuration Release --no-build --verbosity Normal /property:CollectCoverage=True /property:CoverletOutput=D:\BuildAgent\work\workdir\Solution\XUnitTests.UITests1\CoverageReport\UITests1.opencover.xml /property:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover`

the test report format i'm using is `opencover`

this is the coverage i'm getting:

[image]

i have tried using `dotcover` before. it generates proper coverage but it tends to crash due to high memory usage. It's been 4 weeks now and i havent found a solution to this issue.

Comment: Coverage is calculated for unit tests usually. What do you want to cover in UI autotests?

Comment: it covers other projects and returns a coverage when i use dotcover. This project calls UI tests run using a class called SeSVSUnit.Rapise.